# How to render this table?

Tags: tables

I would like to render the following table:

```
               ----------------------------------
               |    Col1           |   Col2     |
-------------------------------------------------
|label 1        |                   |    blah2   |
|               |                   |    blah2   |
----------------        blah1       -------------
|label 2        |       blah1       |    blah3   |
|               |                   |    blah3   |
-------------------------------------------------
```

How can I do this?

So far, I have done this, by replicating the content:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
                     & Col1 & Col2 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{label 1} & blah1 &  blah2\\
                     & blah1 & blah2\\
    \hline
    \textbf{label 2} & blah1 &  blah3\\
                     & blah1 & blah3\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

which is not what I would like to do, since it replicates data. I don't know how to unify row1 and row2 of col1.

Comment: Nope, this is not about how to remove corner. This is about how to unify rows of a column.

Comment: For the border, it seems possible with `\cline` instead of `\hline` +  multirow for the first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}l|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|}
    \cline{2-3}
     \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}& Col1                           & Col2  \\
    \hline
    label 1               & \multirow{2}{1cm}[-4mm]{blah1 blah1} & blah2 blah2\\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
    label 2               &                                & blah3 blah3\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]